# Superpowered SDK: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'. A dikkat occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build''

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to install Superpowered example app on my phone using Android Studio but it's not getting built. It shows an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build''
```

build.gradle code is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.superpowered.hlsexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        def ndkDir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build", '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
        // Windows users: commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd", '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Please help me find the right solution. And/Or guide me on how to add NDK to the current app. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `commandLine "absolute_path_to_ndk/ndk-build"`

Comment: @Onik Still returning same error :/

Answer (score 2):

Just had same problem. Solved it by entering "File -> Project Structure". For my case "Android NDK location" was empty as shown. Clicking "Select" fixed it. 
[image: problematic screen in Android Studio]

Answer (score 1):

Open local.properties. Set ndk.dir to your ndk folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

ndk.dir=

with you ndk folder in local.properties